# Barebones Linux Server Install

Tags: linux

Whats the simplest way to get a barebones linux server installed?
barebones = just enough to get ssh and package manager.

Current I've been using CentOS with server install and removing any packages that I know i do not want installed.

But is there a better way? I just want a simple ssh shell + package management to start with. Hardware is irrelevant since everything is happening in a VM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Debian Stable net install.](http://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/)

Once you have that installed and up and running,  you can apt-get or aptitude install whatever packages you want.  That's how I set up my servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time installing Gentoo will give you just want you want and no more.

Comment: what if you don't want the dev environment including gcc/g++ etc, as it's considered a security risk?

Comment: this isn't the late eighties anymore... an installed compiler is the last you have to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Arch just

```
su -c 'pacman -S sshd'
```

then you have about as barebones as you can get. Pacman its package management system is pretty easy to use and what not also.

Answer (score 0):

You know the guys over at SliceHost have some very nice documentation on setting up Linux VM's. http://articles.slicehost.com/ubuntu-intrepid I am using their service and I found their documentation to be excellent. Particularly in getting a barebones VM up and running. I use their documentation as a reference for setting up iptables firewall and other basic system tasks on other systems. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

JEOS - Just Enough Operating System, an Ubuntu project, should be exactly what you are looking for.